# module.exports object instance for the rest of the app to use

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

In Node, I have the following function/class which instantiates a logger object that I'd like to use in other functions/classes.

In `server.js`,

```
var loggerUtil = require('./utils/logger'),
    logger;

module.exports = function(appInitCb, options) {
    start: function() {
        // Load .env
        dotenv.config({
            silent: true
        });

        // Merge the app configuration with default
        options = _.merge({}, cfgDefaults, options);

        // Create a logger
        logger = loggerUtil.createLogger(options.logger).getLogger();
    },

    logger: logger
};
```

In `main.js`,

```
var server = require('./server');
var logger = require(./server').logger;

server.start({}, {});
logger.info('Hello World');
```

However, it results in the error `TypeError: logger.info is not a function`. Im guessing theres something wrong with the way I export. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a quote ?

Comment: what is that you really want to achieve, as requiring two times './server' module does not make any sense.

Comment: besides, you have to call start first to instantiate the logger object. And if you want to simply require it and not instantiate it again and again then you have to check that logger is already instantiated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export it like so

```
module.exports = function(appInitCb, options) {
   return({
     start: ...
     log: ...
   })
```

}

In your example you are not returning an object which unifies both functions.

You can then require this module like so (thanks @Nivesh):

```
var server = require('./server')();
server.start();
```

## Update

A better approach would be to create an object and assign it directly to the module without the function:

```
var server = {  
   start: function(){...},  
   log: function(){...},  
}  

module.exports = server;
```

That way you can:

```
var server = require('./server');  
server.start()  
server.log()
```

Comment: You can see that Im exporting multiple things. Both a start function and the logger object.

Comment: yes, she's exporting multiple things. Besides this approach is not recommended.

Comment: yeah, now its fine, @nixgadgets you are exporting a function and writing like a object. That's the most basic mistake here.

Comment: should be ```var server = require('./server')();``` as it is a function you can not directly use ```server.start();``` with out executing the function you wont get the returned value.

Comment: is there a better approach than this ? to pass an object around ?